# CSS shadow change side

Tags: css, shadows

```
-moz-box-shadow: inset 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
box-shadow: inset 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

this makes an inset shadow on the top, and left.  I can't figure out to make it on the bottom and the right instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the position values negative:

```
-moz-box-shadow: inset -3px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset -3px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
box-shadow: inset -3px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```